# For DNS and SSL do I need a separate certificate for every (DNS RR) A record?

Tags: ssl, dns, subdomain, cname

So our firm wants to separate out our cloud servers into separate environments, so www.foo.com, test.foo.com and dev.foo.com.  [We may even want to break our subdomains into further sub-domains.]   My boss wants to know how many certificates (for SSL) the firm will need.

I have delved into subdomains and looks like a question of DNS RR (Domain Name Server Resource Records).  I have seen notes about A records and CNAME records and how they interplay.  I am thinking that a mixture of A and CNAME records should suffice to separate out our namespace.

What of the certificates though, do we need an SSL certificate for every A record?  My boss is keen to reduce cost (as are all bosses).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation is done based on what name is in your URL.  If your URL contains the IP address you must have a certificate for the IP, if you have a name the certificate must contain a name or a wildcard matching the name. It will not do any DNS lookups to find a different name for validation. These things together mean for example:

- If you use URL's with `www.example.com`, `foo.example.com`, `example.com` and some IP all of these must be contained in the certificate even if these are at the end the same server. This requirement of containing all names you use in the URL can not be lessened by making `www.example.com` a CNAME for `example.com` or by having a RR record for IP pointing back to `example.com`.
- wildcards match only a single left-most label. That is `*.example.com` matches `foo.example.com` but not `example.com` or `www.foo.example.com`. And you can have only a single left-most wildcard, i.e. no `foo.*.example.com` or even `*.*.example.com`.
- You can combine several subjects into the certificate, ypu can use wildcards or you could use different certificates for each name. The last option might give problems if you have different names with the same IP address, because then the client needs to support [Server Name Indication (SNI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).